# Multiple kml layers overlapping info window

Tags: google-maps, kml, infowindow

I have 5 kml layers in my google map, but when an infowindow is shown from layer A, and a marker is clicked from layer B, the marker of B will overlap, or sometimes "hides" behind the infowindow from layer A depending on the z-index. If you click on another marker within the same layer, the other infowindow will close. I want only one infowindow opened at a time OR the last clicked infowindow having the highest z-index (meaning, on top).

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033265/google-maps-v3-z-index-issue-with-multiple-kml-layers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628175/issue-with-infowindows-remaining-active-when-another-kml-layer-is-selected-goo) and [this](http://j3elearning.host56.com/mapTest/index.htm). The first links tells me load the kml layers in another order (not an option for me), the second link I don't understand and the third link is the preferred behavior. I think the third link is actually an implementation of the second link.

I tried the fix given in the third link, I combined it with my own code:

```
    var map;
    var layers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
// create a new info window for the KML (outage) layer and the geo-coded house marker
function addKmlClickHandler(layers) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers, "click", function(event) {
        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setOptions({
            pixelOffset:    event.pixelOffset,
            content:        event.featureData.infoWindowHtml,
            position:       event.latLng
        });
        infowindow.open(map);
    });
}


      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var long = position.coords.longitude;
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
    keyboardShortcuts : false, 
    mapTypeControl : false, 
    mapMaker : false, 
    overviewMapControl : false, 
    panControl : false, 
    rotateControl : false, 
    scaleControl : false, 
    scrollwheel : false, 
    streetViewControl : false,
    zoomControl : false, 
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    //  alert('Your latitude is '+lat+' and longitude is '+long);



        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        layers [0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('...', 
      {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: false, map: map});
      google.maps.event.addListener(layers, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
        alert('test');
    });
      layers [1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('...', 
      {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: false, map: map});
    layers [2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('...', 
      {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: false, map: map});
    layers [3] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('...', 
      {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: false, map: map});
    layers [4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('...', 
      {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: false, map: map});
        /*var kmlUrl = '';
    var kmlOptions = {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: true,
      map: map
    };

    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions); */
    //alert('kml data geladen?');
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'You are here!',
      });
        var image = '...';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          title: 'You are here!',
      });
      infowindow.open(map,marker);

    }
 addKmlClickHandler(layers); // this should do the trick
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
      }
  }

function toggleLayer(i) {
  if (layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }

}
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to do it easier, like looking for a click event on a [kml layer marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070837/adding-click-event-to-kmllayer-placemarks-and-markers) and if yes, hide all other infowindows?

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], 'click', function(hideotherinfowindows) {
    ...
});
```

Unfortunatelly I haven't found anywhere if it is actually possible to hide all infowindows except the clicked one.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as is.  Can you fix it and provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. suppress the automatic infowindows on the KmlLayers.
2. Add your own click listener to open an infowindow on clicks
3. Only create one infowindow, move it between the markers (use that same infowindow for the "you are here" marker).

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/www_satpacktravel_com_api_v5b.html)

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function openIW(KMLevent) {
  infoWindow.close();
  infoWindow.setOptions(
    { 
     content: KMLevent.featureData.infoWindowHtml,
     position: KMLevent.latLng,
     pixelOffset: KMLevent.pixelOffset
    });
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], "click", openIW);
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[1], "click", openIW);
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[2], "click", openIW);
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[3], "click", openIW);
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[4], "click", openIW);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() { infoWindow.close();});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nVN3/1/)

Comment: 1. I changed `suppressInfoWindows:false` to `suppressInfoWindows:true` per KML layer. 2. I have added your script, and included an `alert('test');`. 3. I have added 5 times `google.maps.event.addListener(layers[i], "click", openIW);` where i is a number from 0 to 4. When I click on a marker, i see an alert message which means that the click listener is OK. When I remove the alert my infowindow doesn't have content and is shown top-left of the gmap (not near the marker). I'm not sure about the `infoWindow.setOptions`, what is `FTevent.infoWindowHtml` and `FTevent.latLng`? Thanks so far!

Comment: Did you compare your code to the working example? Any javascript errors? Can you create a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes I compared my code, and the only different I could find was what you posted as an answer. There were no js errors. I have made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nVN3/ but i don't know why, only 1 kml feed is showing (you should see 5 different colored markers). I am new to using jsfiddle so maybe I did something wrong when copy pasting. (you need to accept geolocation in order to see it working).

Comment: Please rework it not to require GPS. That won't be a factor in the problem and just makes it more complicated (the goal should be a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated my answer to account for the difference between a [KmlMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlMouseEvent) and a [FusionTablesMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent) (the original code came from a FusionTablesLayer example). [working fiddle (does not require geolocation)](http://jsfiddle.net/9nVN3/1/)

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now. Also thanks about the remark of reworking the code. I cleaned up my code and got it now more structured and I actually understand it now more than before.